# Desktop WiFi app to Sync with Mobile app

Tags: iphone, python, mobile, wifi

I need your help! I want to create a desktop app and a mobile app to sync data between them. 
Imagine a simple TO-DO list app. I also want to know if you think this is the best solution.

My first idea is to create a python app in order to target all possible operative systems, and then create the mobile ones to sync between them.

Any idea, suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you intend the desktop app to be the server for the mobile app client? Or are both the desktop app and mobile app clients of some server on the web?

Either are entirely possible and workable; however if the server is at a known location on the web, any mobile client instance can know where to find it - if it is running on a local network, some extra configuration will be needed (ie the server address).

Comment: No server, the computer will host the files ( Desktop App )